# unable to set menubar and title bar colour in qgis

Tags: python, qgis

I wanna change qgis mainwindow menubar's and titlebar's background and text colour using python plugin I used following code

```
qgis.mainWindow().setWindowTitle("mytitle")

qgis.mainWindow().setStyleSheet("

QMenuBar{
          background-color:blue;
        }
 ")
```

but this change only background of menubar but does effect on the menu option of the menu bar I wanna customize menu option text colour according to background colour.

I also want to change tilte bar colour please let me know the solotion

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a dark theme to QGIS by going to `Options > Application > UITheme` and selecting `Night Mapping`.

If that's not how you like it, you can at least look at the nightmapping theming to see how it's done and tweak to your liking.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/resources/themes/Night%20Mapping/style.qss